# Regex to replace chinese punctuation with English comma in Python

Tags: python, regex, punctuation

For Chinese words: `上海，北京、武汉；重庆。欢迎你！你好`, I want to replace Chinese punctuation 
with comma, how can I do that using regex in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do with `re` module

```
import re
str='上海，北京、武汉；重庆。欢迎你！你好'
s = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]',',',str)
print(s)
```

**Output:**

```
上海,北京,武汉,重庆,欢迎你,你好
```

**Explanation**,

`[^\w\s]`- Match a single character **Not** present in the list below-

```
1. \w matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
2. \s matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
```

Comment: Thanks. May I ask what's `^\w\s` means?

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, but there is one exclamation point left:

```
strings = "上海，北京、武汉；重庆。欢迎你！你好"    
punc = "[\u3002\uff1b\uff0c\uff1a\u201c\u201d\uff08\uff09\u3001\uff1f\u300a\u300b]"
string = re.sub(punc, ",", strings)
print(string)
```

Output:

```
上海,北京,武汉,重庆,欢迎你！你好
```

Comment: The exclamation mark is a Fullwidth Exclamation Mark which is `U+FF01`. It works if you add that in.

Comment: Thanks. Are there characters could represent all Chinese punctuations ?

Comment: From what I found, Chinese punctuation are spread into two range: FF00—FFEF which are [Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/halfwidth-and-fullwidth-forms/), and 3000—303F which are [CJK Symbols and Punctuation](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/cjk-symbols-and-punctuation/).